# Inbound emails in SugarCRM not receiving if they are read from other email clients

Tags: email, gmail, sugarcrm, email-client

We are working on SugarCRM (Community edition) email integration from gmail account. Everything is working fine with calling email schedule job 1 minute using cron jobs. The problem is, its not reading the emails which are marked as read (When users directly see the email from google before it reaches to SugarCRM).

I don't know whether it is a limitation of SugarCRM or any work around. How to read the emails if they are read in gmail.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behaviour but could be changed in modules/InboundEmail/InboundEmail.php getNewMessageIds(

There the UNSEEN is hard coded and not configuarable.

There is also a way to overwrite that in a update save way. Take a look http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f3/upgrade-safe-custo-handlecreatecase-82635/